# Job sites for applied/interdisciplinary mathematics related to computer science?

Tags: computational-geometry, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm looking for job sites in applied/interdisciplinary mathematics, more specially, say postdocs or higher positions in mathematics and medical imaging, mathematics and computer vision. I'm aware of mostly all the popular job sites, mathjobs, euro math jobs, jobs.ac.uk, nordic math jobs etc etc, but most of the jobs there are of 'pure' nature, with very few for applied/interdisciplinary.

I'm trying to find postdoctoral position in mathematical imaging problems, which would use significant amount of conformal/quasiconformal mappings, Riemann surfaces, differential geometry etc. Looking into individual group's webpage is too much work. But if there's an webpage containing all the information, that'll be much better!

So, if you know any such website for the above (for Europe(preferable) and US), I'd appreciate if you could pass them onto me. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question is not appropriate for this site. [Career questions are mostly off-topic](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/240/career-questions), and [lists of links are not what Stack Exchange is about](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/781/where-can-i-share-great-resources-i-come-across). Besides this is something that I'd recommend you ask to your academic contacts (your professors, their former students, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 google lists:

```
Imageworld

visionlist
```

You can join these. They have a lot of information.